# How do I cut everything on each line starting with a multi-character string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, cut

How do I cut everything starting with a given multi-character string using a common shell command?

e.g., given:

```
foo+=bar
```

I want:

```
foo
```

i.e., cut everything starting with `+=`

`cut` doesn't work because it only takes a single-character delimiter, not a multi-character string:

```
$ echo 'foo+=bar' | cut -d '+=' -f 1
cut: bad delimiter
```

If I can't use `cut`, I would consider using `perl` instead, or if there's another shell command that is more commonly installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'sed' command to do this:

```
string='foo+=bar'
echo ${string} | sed 's/+=.*//g'
foo
```

or if you're using Bash shell, then use the below parameter expansion (recommended) since it doesn't create unnecessary pipeline and another sed process and so is efficient:

```
echo ${string%%\+\=*}
```

or

```
echo ${string%%[+][=]*}
```

Answer (score 3):

`cut` only allows single character delimiter.

You may use `bash` string manipulation:

```bash
s='foo+=bar'
echo "${s%%+=*}"

foo
```

or use more powerful `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '\\+=' '{print $1}' <<< "$s"
foo
```

`'\\+='` is a regex that matches `+` followed by `=` character.

Comment: The parameter expansion `echo "${s%%[+=]*}"` is not correct. The question is to remove everything starting with the 'multicharacter' pattern += This expression removes any pattern starting with + or = and so appears to work here, but let's say if `s='foo+bar'` or `s='foo=bar'` even then the result will be 'foo' which should not be the case. It should be modified as:
`echo "${s%%[+][=]*}"`
or
`echo "${s%%\+\=*}"`

Comment: Good point @Pavan. However there is no need to escape `+` and `+` there just `"${s%%+=*}"` will work

Comment: @RobBednark: It is an old answer but wondering if it ever worked for you?